# Ubuntu 21.10 Thunderbird - IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

Tags: thunderbird, 21.10

**Thunderbird 91.3.1**

If I start `Thunderbird` from the `terminal`, and then select any email message to read, I see the following error...

```
IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

###!!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PClientManager::Msg_ForgetFutureClientSource Processing error: message was deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)
```

Google doesn't give any real clue about what an "IPDL protocol error" is.

To troubleshoot, I logged into a separate Ubuntu account where `Thunderbird` had never been used. I started `Thunderbird` from the `terminal` and created a mail account using one of my Google gmail accounts. Read any message, and got the same problem. So it's not an account-specific problem.

**Partial log from `terminal`...**

```
~$ thunderbird
[calBackendLoader] Using Thunderbird's libical backend
[LDAPModuleLoader] Using LDAPDirectory.jsm
[MsgSendModuleLoader] Using MessageSend.jsm
[SmtpModuleLoader] Using SmtpService.jsm
console.debug: WebExtensions: 
  Compact Headers loaded
1642775310275   tbsortfolders.folderPane    DEBUG   Init
1642775310275   tbsortfolders.folderPane    DEBUG   Add observer
console.debug: "Trying to load /usr/lib/thunderbird/libotr.so"
console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so from system's standard library locations"
console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so.5 from system's standard library locations"
console.debug: "Successfully loaded OTR library libotr.so.5 from system's standard library locations"
console.debug: "Successfully loaded OpenPGP library librnp.so version 0.15.2+git20210806.dd923a4e.MZLA from /usr/lib/thunderbird/librnp.so"
console.debug: "Found 0 public keys and 0 secret keys (0 protected, 0 unprotected)"
console.debug: "Successfully loaded optional OpenPGP library libgpgme.so.11 from system's standard library locations"
console.debug: "gpgme version: 1.14.0-unknown"

IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

###!!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PClientManager::Msg_ExpectFutureClientSource Processing error: message was deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)

IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

###!!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PClientManager::Msg_ForgetFutureClientSource Processing error: message was deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)
```

Any ideas what this error is about?

Comment: Same problem here. (Ubuntu 21.10, Thunderbird 91.3.1)

Comment: I have a very similar terminal output. However, thunderbird works fine for me. Still, I am very interested in the solution to these errors as well, even when they don't seem to be the source/indicators of your crashes.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.04 and Thunderbird 91.5, I get the same error message, but my entire box locks up (even alt-sysreg-b does nothing).

Comment: @JohnAnderson Do you have any Thunderbird extensions or plug-ins installed? How about gnome-shell extensions?

Comment: No Thunderbird extensions or plug-ins installed. I have several system gnome extensions installed, but only one is actually enabled: [window llst](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/).

Comment: @JohnAnderson Please start a new question.

Comment: Same here, Ubuntu 20.04.4 and thunderbird 91.9.1. I used evolution mailclient for a while, but now wanted to switch back to thunderbird.